# How to upload Subreports in Jaspersoft Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Can anyone tell me how to upload sub reports in Jaspersoft Server and connect it with the main report???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To upload a subreport in *JasperReport Server*  go to JR Server

1:- Right click on the any directory where you want to save the subrepot.

2:- then "Add resource" then "File" and then "JRXML", brouse subreport and give any name.

3:- Open Ireport and go to main report and from palett drag "Sub report" and browse subreport from your machine.

4:- then add parameters in case you have .

5:- Then select subreport and go to property section and "Sub report expression" property, edit and change the expression like "repo:/path of subreport jrxml in jasperreport"